# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1) - Exception error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to save the details into the database. This is the part when i create the table and the columns. But I'm getting an exception error near "(".

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL ," + TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + DETAILS + " TEXT NOT NULL, ("+TITLE+", "+DATE+" UNIQUE)); ");
}
```

Can anyone could help me out?

Comment: Do you want date to be unique or date AND title?

Comment: Both of them @trebron

Comment: **Wild guess**: Your table name contains spaces! OR it is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Your create table statement is not correct.

The error is on this part:

```java
("+TITLE+", "+DATE+" UNIQUE)
```

According to [the documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), if you want your title and date to be unique (the combination of both fields), your create statement must be

```java
db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL ," + TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + DETAILS + " TEXT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT uniquetitledate UNIQUE ("+TITLE+", "+DATE+")); ");
```

Or, if you want your title to be unique and your date to be unique, your create statement must be

```java
db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL ," + TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + DETAILS + " TEXT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT uniquetitle UNIQUE ("+TITLE+"), CONSTRAINT uniquedate UNIQUE ("+DATE+")); ");
```